# Using Javascript to scroll through a specific window

Tags: javascript, scroll

I'm pretty new to JS. I'm not totally unreceptive but I can't manage to get this to work.

I am trying to code a simple script in JS which will be able to scroll through the follower window of Instagram. Now, I see that to scroll through a normal window I'd just have to use window.scrollTo(x, y) but for this problem it doesn't work.

If you don't know which window I mean, you can try it out if you log into Instagram on your computer. Go on a random profile with a few followers and click on the displayed number of followers. Now another small window opens.
What I want the to do is: I want the script to scroll down that smaller window. If I use window.scrollTo(x, y) it just scrolls through the larger page underneath.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of `window.scrollTo(x, y);`, did you try to get the element that you want to scroll and run the function on that? `document.getElementById('IdOfElement').scrollTo(x, y);`

Comment: I actually had played around with that, but I didn't manage to make it work. As I said, I'm not good with JS. I didn't know how to get the ID of the element.

Comment: You'd have to inspect the HTML using your browser. Since I don't know what the HTML looks like, I can't help you.

Comment: I tried finding it out by using "Inspect Element" on FF, but I wasn't successful. As said in the OP, it's just the small window that pops up if you click on someone's follower count on instagram. That's the window I want to scroll.
I'd be grateful for any little help.